# How to expand Layer Collision Matrix in Physics Settings in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, settings, project, game-physics

I am trying to disable the Interactable on Player cell in the layer collision matrix, but I am missing those two rows and columns from the matrix altogether (See attached images).

Here is what I tried to fix the problem:

1. Ensuring all other settings in the Project Physics Settings window are identical to a tutorial I am watching.
2. Discovered the available cells are identical to the default layers. In my settings - There are three blank layers (Builtin layers 3,6 and 7)
3. Checking if problem persists in other versions of Unity, and unfortunately it does.
4. Manually adding the missing layers (In User layers - see my settings). It expanded the matrix, but didn't created any effect.

Video: [VR With Andrew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2QYjhu4_G4)

[image: My Settings]
Attached images:
[image: Desired Settings]

Comment: So simply add more [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) ... ?

Comment: Thanks @derHugo. Unfortunately that didn't worked. These layers should be built-in (As you can see in my settings we have 3 blank layers). Your advice helped me to expand the matrix, but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: Well obviously after adding the new layers you also will have to assign them to your objects ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. This can indeed be solved with manually adding additional layers, but please make sure you're attributing the relevant game-objects with the corresponding layers. In an event of a bug, make sure you didn't attributed the children of the game-object with the layers.